# How to test react components when fetch in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have component where I perform two `fetch` operations in `componentDidMount`. I want to test this and I have to be honest: it's not clear to me how to proceed at all.

The point is that it seems that there isn't a "standard" way to proceed. Essentially what I find more confusing is:

- **How to mock:** apparently, you can mock asynchronous calls using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) or [jest-fetch-mock](https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock).
- **How to manage the lifecycle and structure the tests:**

  - In [this](https://github.com/nilshartmann/jest-playground) article in Approach 3 is explained how to implement a test using enzyme and jest-fetch-mock.
  - In [this](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html) article it is explained how to test async calls with jest only.

It's not very clear to me when I should use one approach/library instead of the other.

This is a simplified version of my function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(URL, {
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Error loading data from " + URL);
        }
    }).then(data => {
        if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {
            this.setState({
                data: data,
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid data from " + URL);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(URL + ' error: ', error);
        this.setState({error});
    });

    const payload = {...};

    fetch(URL2, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Error loading data from " + URL2);
        }
    }).then(data => {
        if (!_.isEmpty(data2)) {
            this.setState({
                data2: data2
            });
        } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid data from " + URL2);
        }

    }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({error, isLoading: false});
    });
```

}

What I want to test is:

- Supposing that the fetch (`GET`) went well, test the updated `state` respect the form that I want (so both case where `data` is well/bad formed).
- Supposing that fetching fails, test that `state` is updated with `error`
- Notice that I want to perform similar tests for the second fetch too.

Of course I will need a mocking mechanism to mock the two answers (for `GET` and `POST` operations) but is not clear how should I do it, or how to test the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to mock the api call. `fetch` has its own library tests so you don't need to test if `fetch` works. But if you really need to test your method, you can just use `jest` - https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html . Forget the jest-fetch-mock. You can test:

1. Was the method `componentDidMount` called?
2. Was `yourMethod` called?
3. After `yourMethod` finished, did the change occurred? (Your new state is the expected  one?)

Just remember not to test the libraries themselves, or to go very deep into the component tree. You should only test atomically. One thing at a time.

Now:

You can use `async/await` or just test the fetch itself. First of all, you should abstract those `fetch`'es to their own methods. Now. If all you do is concatenate promises and if u get everything correctly u set the state, you just need to , on the test file, resolve that promise, and on its callback, check if the state changed to what you wanted.

Again, this has all you need to know: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#promises

And if you need one more resource here you go: https://codereviewvideos.com/course/react-redux-and-redux-saga-with-symfony-3/video/testing-javascript-s-fetch-with-jest-happy-path

Comment: And in particular, how do you test 3.? Thank for your answer btw :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but in all the documentation that you provided me, there is no description on how to test the component state. And then, what is the purpose of testing the isolated fetch calls? Since we mock the data, we are simply testing that the returned data is the one that we mocked. Not very useful.

Comment: you have a original state, say A, and a expected result, say object C. Then, you run your methods that change the state to a state B. You just need to make sure that B === C. You can either compare objects or use https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme to help you out accessing react inner methods like state. What do you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to assert state/snapshot after the data from remote source are received. Even with mocking it's still goes asynchronously. So you can use e.g. setTimeout to postpone assertion:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import sinon from "sinon";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

sinon.stub(fetch, "Promise").returns(
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve( { name: "Hello" } )
  })
);


class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "none"
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetch( "https://swapi.co/api/people/1" ),
          data = await res.json();
    this.setState({ name: data.name });
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>{ this.state.name }</h1>;
  }
}

describe( "component with fetch", () => {
  test( "state gets updated with the fetch", ( done ) => {
    const wrapper = shallow( <Test /> );
    setTimeout(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      const state = wrapper.instance().state;
      console.log(state);
      done();
    }, 10 );
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

We generally `test the state` that the lifecycle methods have changed by mocking the fetch calls. `Avoid using setTimeout` in tests as you never know how much time the fetchMock is gonna take, so you can use `await` instead of that. For example:

```
import React from "react";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import fetchMock from "fetch-mock";
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent";

describe(() => {
    it("should set the state after fetching data", () => {
        // arrange
        fetchMock.get(`https://www.example.com`, mockResponse);
        const wrapper = shallow(<TestComponent>);
        
        // act
        await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();

        // assert
        expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual(newStateObject);

    })

})
```